# NameError: global name 'pair' is not defined

Tags: python

Is there an in build python module for `pair`,I couldn't find any if not how do I resolve the below error?

```
def main (v1):
#def find_busy_intervals(v1):

  if v1 == None or len(v1) == 0 :
    return None

  v2 = []
  v2.append(pair(v1[0].first,v1[0].second))

  for i in xrange(1, len(v1)):
    x1 = v1[i].first
    y1 = v1[i].second
    x2 = v2[len(v2) - 1].first
    y2 = v2[len(v2) - 1].second

    if y2 >= x1:
      v2[len(v2)-1].second = max(y1, y2)
    else:
      v2.append(pair(x1,y1))

  return v2;

if __name__=="__main__":
    v1= [(1,5),(3,7),(4,6),(6,8),(10,12),(11,15)]
    v2 = main (v1)
    print v2
```

Error:-

```
C:\Dropbox\scripts>python pythonCSharp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonCSharp.py", line 26, in <module>
    v2 = main (v1)
  File "pythonCSharp.py", line 9, in main
    v2.append(pair(v1[0].first,v1[0].second))
NameError: global name 'pair' is not defined
```

Comment: What is `pair`?  Do you maybe mean `tuple`?

Comment: ...what did you think it would do? You resolve the name error, in this case, by not referring to a thing that doesn't exist.

Comment: What is *pair* supposed to do? If its only a two-element tuple you could simply drop it so only the parentheses remain.

Comment: pair function is missing

Comment: @mahdibahri not so much "missing" as "never actually existed".

Comment: try to remplace pair function with  global.pair()

Comment: if you want something tell us what you want exactly

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to have a module for something as simple. The `pair` class that you need can be easily constructed with [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple
pair = namedtuple('pair', 'first second')
```

Now you can use `pair` like in that code, but notice that the elements of `v1` must be pairs too:

```
v1 = [pair(1,5), pair(3,7), pair(4,6), pair(6,8), pair(10,12), pair(11,15)]
```

... and you cannot *assign to them*, like in

```
v2[len(v2)-1].second = max(y1, y2)
```

Thus perhaps you then should use a custom class:

```
class pair:
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
```

Though easiest would be just to ditch this `pair` and use plain tuples, but you need to rethink your algorithm so that you don't need the equivalent of the assignment `v2[len(v2)-1].second = max(y1, y2)` as tuples / named tuples cannot be mutated.